# Wordpress how to get the text that is in the content textarea on the edit post page

Tags: wordpress

How do i get the text that is in the "content" textarea, of the edit post page, when saving post

example:

```
class Class {
    function save() {
        echo "content of textarea";
    }

}
if( class_exists( 'Class' ) ) {
    $Class = new Class();
        add_action( 'save_post', array(&$Class, 'save') );
}
```

more specifically, the textarea that has the text you type in when creating or editing a post is called id="content", I want to get the text from this box when clicking update button when saving a post.

Comment: You mean `the_content()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on the given link: [save_post API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post#bodyContent)

According to first example:

```
function my_project_updated_send_email( $post_id ) {

 // If this is just a revision, don't send the email.
 //if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) )
 // return;

 //$post_title = get_the_title( $post_id );
 //$post_url = get_permalink( $post_id );
 //$subject = 'A post has been updated';

 //$message = "A post has been updated on your website:\n\n";
 //$message .= $post_title . ": " . $post_url;

 // This is how you get the Content with Post ID
     $content_post = get_post($post_id);
     $content = $content_post->post_content;
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'my_project_updated_send_email' );
```

Do the changes accordingly, And hope this help you.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you want to do with it and in what stage ...

But generally , all the post ( or page ) is inside the `$data[]` array or `$postarr`, so post_content will be in `$content = $data['post_content'];` and title will be in `$data['post_title']` and so on ( post id will be `$postid = $postarr["ID"];` ).

Like I said , it depends on what you want to do with it , ut here is an example  :

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_data' , '99', 2 ); // or add_action

function filter_post_data( $data , $postarr ) {
    // Change post title
    $data['post_title'] .= '_suffix'; // add surfix to title
    $data['post_content'] = $content .$my_new_content  ; // do whatever    
    return $data;
}
```

The `wp_insert_post_data` is called by `wp_insert_post` ( and others ) which are called by `save_post` - hence it is quite low-level function which lets you intercept and modify the content at an early stage ..

Just for general reference - here are the values for `$postarr`

```
   'post_status'
   'post_type'
   'post_author'
   'ping_status'
   'post_parent'
   'menu_order'
   'to_ping'
   'pinged'
   'post_password'
   'guid'
   'post_content_filtered'
   'post_excerpt'
   'import_id'
   'post_content'
   'post_title'
   'ID'
   'post_date'
   'post_date_gmt'
   'comment_status'
   'post_name'
   'post_modified'
   'post_modified_gmt'
   'post_mime_type'
   'comment_count'
   'ancestors'
   'post_category'
   'tags_input'
   'filter'
```

and for `$data`:

```
   'post_author',
   'post_date',
   'post_date_gmt',
   'post_content',
   'post_content_filtered',
   'post_title',
   'post_excerpt',
   'post_status',
   'post_type',
   'comment_status',
   'ping_status',
   'post_password',
   'post_name',
   'to_ping',
   'pinged',
   'post_modified',
   'post_modified_gmt',
   'post_parent',
   'menu_order',
   'guid'
```